# BeginInvoke activates form

Tags: c#, winforms, begininvoke

I have a WinForms application written in C#.  The first screen to appear when it opens is a dashboard screen that can take some time to load.  The data loading method is called using BeginInvoke on delegate.  That part is fine, my problem is when I want to load the read data into some grids.  The code to get me back to my UI thread looks like so

```
BeginInvoke(new Action<DashboardDataInfo, int>(LoadDashboardData), data, outbox);
```

This all happens without error.  My problem is the dashboard Form will jump to the top of the screen.  If data loading has taken long enough the user could be already onto another from in the app  (so this is really annoying). The LoadDashboardData method doesn't do much besides assign the DataSource property of a few DataGridView controls.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the `BeginInvoke` will be the cause of this. Please provide the code of `LoadDashboardData` so we have the complete context.

Comment: Since LoadDashboardData is somewhat large I decided to do the next obvious thing and comment out every line, then went through re-enabling code to see when the jumping resumes.  So yea, I had some logic buried deep in a method call that was calling Focus.  I am going to close this question, even though you did technically get me to answer it.